# Debug print by macro with variable names

Tags: c, macros, printf, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

Is there a way, how to neatly pass variable name and its value to a debug macro? What I'm using now is "just" this.

```
#if DEBUG_LEVEL >= 1
#define DEBUG_PRINT(fmt, ...) do{\
fprintf(stderr, ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW "[DEBUG]: %s:%c\t", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
fprintf(stderr, fmt ANSI_COLOR_RESET, __VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...)
#endif

#define STR(x) #x
```

It's by all means fine, but when I want to output what variable belongs to which name, I use construct like this and it easily gets too cumbersome.

```
DEBUG_PRINT(STR(min_a)": %u\t"STR(max_a)": %u\t"STR(min_c)": %u\t"STR(max_c)":%u\t"STR(min_m)": %u\t"STR(max_m)":%u\t"STR(d)": %d\n", min_a, max_a, min_c, max_c, min_m, max_m, d);
```

Is there a way, how to get rid of those `STR(x)` in `DEBUG_PRINT` in such a way, that variable name stays visible and the overall formatting stays pretty much the same? I don't mind putting in the format specifiers, though my first thought was to get rid of those as well, if possible. The most important thing is to retain variable number of arguments.

So my question is, how to write a macro, that do this "pretty printing", without the need to call STR(x) - something like this: `DEBUG_PRINT_VARS(min_a, max_a, min_c, max_c, min_m, max_m, d)`

Comment: I see no advantage in what you wrote compared with: `DEBUG_PRINT("min_a: %u\tmax_a: %u\tmin_c: %u\tmax_c:%u\tmin_m: %u\tmax_m:%u\td: %d\n", min_a, max_a, min_c, max_c, min_m, max_m, d);` — what is the benefit of the `STR` macros in your eyes?  This is how I'd write a `printf()` statement to print the variables.  If you used `DEBUG_PRINT_VARS(min_a, max_a, min_c, max_c, min_m, max_m, d)` as your macro call, then the implementation would use a variant of `STR(x)` to stringify each name (and iteration to process the variable args, and so on), but that's rather different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, well, that's the idea, not to write the stringification so tediously like this. Or writing it the way how you used it, but rather like the call of `DEBUG_PRINT_VARS(min_a, max_a, min_c, max_c, min_m, max_m, d)` - which I have trouble writing.

Comment: We can't answer the question you didn't ask.  I'm not sure I'm prepared to do the research necessary to get [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to do the job, but I think it can.  Type information is a problem.  I've used `DEBUG_PRINT_INT(int_var);` and variations on that theme — no variable length argument list.  I think if you're going to make `DEBUG_PRINT_VARS()` work for arbitrary types, you're likely to need: `DEBUG_PRINT_VARS(min_a, "%u", max_a, "%u", …)` to specify the format/type as well as the variable name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You could try to use `_Generic` to produce common conversion specifications.

Comment: @KerrekSB: be my guest — there's room for an answer below.  There are advantages to controlling the format explicitly; you can add lengths, etc. so that the output is more easily read.  But I'd be curious to see how `_Generic` would work without bloating the code.  You can only concatenate string literals, and any `_Generic` expression isn't a string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I sort of solved it for now by using MAP macro (https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro), edited it for allowing two argument function, and then having:

```
#if DEBUG_LEVEL >= 1
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) do{\
fprintf(stderr, ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW "[DEBUG]: %s:%d\t", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
MAP(PRINT_ARG, __VA_ARGS__); \
fprintf(stderr, "\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET);}while(0)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...)
#endif

#define PRINT_ARG(x, y) fprintf(stderr, #x": "y"\t", x);
```

and using it like this

```
DEBUG_PRINT(min_a, "%u", max_a, "%u", min_c, "%u", max_c, "%u", min_m, "%u", max_m, "%u", d, "%d");
```

It answers the question itself, so that's the reason why am I posting it as an answer, though I'd be really interested in finding out a way, how to produce conversion specifiers **implicitly**